# Best way to implement lock in C#

Tags: c#, multithreading, synchronization

I have an object which is used to access a SQL Server table, do insert / updates.

I have two windows services, which use the same object to read/write to the same table.

To preserve the integrity, I was using Mutex lock and release on this object.  But of late getting sync errors (Object synchronization method was called from an unsynchronized block of code). Hence I am adding a bool to identify the caller (In the code below bool isThreadOwnedLockAskingToRelease in 'Release' method). Will this resolve the sync issues and is this the correct way?

**Class ST**

```
   public ST() //constructor
{
    Mutex stBusy = utils.GetMutex(@"ST");
    bool lockAcquired = false;
    lock (ex)
    {
        //open connection
        // build dataset
        // close conn
    }
}
// ...

public bool Lock(string nameOfLock)
{
    if (stBusy != null)
    {
        if (stBusy.WaitOne(2000))
        {
            lockAcquired = true;
            //...
        }

    }
  return lockAcquired;
}

public void Release(string NameOfUnlocker, bool isThreadOwnedLockAskingToRelease)
{
    if (stBusy != null && isThreadOwnedLockAskingToRelease)
    {
        stBusy.ReleaseMutex();            
    }
}
```

**Class Service1:**

```
        ST st;
        bool smlock =  st.Lock("STLock");
        if (smlock)
        {
            st = new ST(); // construct object
            // do work
            st.Release("STLock",smlock); // 2nd param added to identify the locker
        }
```

**Class Service2:**

```
ST st1;
bool lockOwner = st1.Lock("QM");
st1= new StatusTable();
//Do work
// Unlock the status table
st1.Release("QM", lockOwner); // Addl. parameter added to fix sync issue
```

Comment: Why not just use default lock commands ? (Lock <object> {code}

Comment: No, the right way would be to acquire the lock and then release. If you can't acquire the lock, why do you still continue and run the query? Isn't the lock unnecessary then?

Comment: I would suggest the correct way is to use Stored procedures to call these read and write operations and use SQL transactions from the services. And not use any shared objects between the services and apply sync later, this I think is a tedious task to maintain sync between all such services. Is there any specific reason why you are using this shared object instead of the transaction approach?

Comment: Hi neo, well I have no idea why transactions were not preferred because code was written by someone who is not in team.

Comment: Hi Jurion, lock is used within the object constructor (class ST). However, as per my understanding, Mutex is used since two different processes (i.e. windows services - refer Service1 and Servcie2 in my code sample) would be using the same object

Comment: I think you shouldn't be using lock on ST constructor for the same reason you're using a Mutex later on.